# Проблема при настройке источника( Problem when configuring the source)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello for the first time on the forum please do not judge strictly. So this: according to the instructions from the official site ROS.org I use the instructions for setting up the source. Or rather on this syslyk Http: //wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installat .... I lead a command for receiving software from the site packages.ros.org. To be more precise, this "sudo sh -c 'echo" deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu "and then I also drive this part of the program" (lsb_release -sc) main "> / etc / apt / sources .list.d / ros-latest.list '". Then they give me: deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu sh: 2: Syntax.error: word.unexpected (there should not be a dot in two places, I'm sorry) Please help !!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298979/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0(-problem-when-configuring-the-source)/) by [Slavanka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36722/slavanka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-07-30**:
Please use english, otherwise an answer to your question could maybe help you, but the vast majority of other users could not understand it.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-30**:
Thanks for translating your question to English. Can you please do the same for your entire title?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-30**:
Also, your question, to me, is confusing. Can you please try to edit it so that it's more clear what you're trying to do, what you've done, and what the results are (please copy and paste any errors that you receive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seams you somehow broke the command? You should just copy exact line into your command line... Exactly this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0